# Declare and initialize 2 dimensional array typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, multidimensional-array

I have below code:

simpleData is an array , gets data from server.

```
var secondaryData = [];
this.simpleData.forEach(function(team,teamIndex) {
      let p0=0,p1=0,p2=0,p3=0,p4=0;
       team.components.forEach(function(component,index) {
          let tempData = []; //Single Dimensional array
           p0 = component.priority0;
           p1 = component.priority1;
           p2 = component.priority2;
           p3 = component.priority3;
           p4 = component.priority4;
        tempData.push(p0);tempData.push(p1);tempData.push(p2);
        tempData.push(p3);tempData.push(p4);
        secondaryData[teamIndex][index].push(tempData);
       });
     });
```

I want a two dimensional array, secondaryData[team][component] = array of values derived. I am getting undefined error at secondaryData. I am not sure, why. Could some one help.

Data structure of simpleData:

```
[{"name":"abc","components":[{"name":"name1","a0":0,"a1":6,"a2":36,"a3":44,"a4":59},....]}]
```

Comment: Try this `let secondaryData: any[][] = [];`

Comment: It would greatly help if you would supply the data structure of simpleData.

Comment: let secondaryData: any[][] = []; Is the size mandatory? because I am getting error: "typeerror: cannot read property '0' of undefined". I have also tried secondaryData[teamIndex].push(tempData). Getting erorr: cannot use push of undefined.

Comment: Fixed the same by initalizing secondaryData[teamIndex] = new Array(); after first loop.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the same by initalizing secondaryData[teamIndex] = new Array(); after first loop. Closing this thread.